# This is related to video sdk API, Java code, Android

Tags: java, android, videosdk.live

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean
org.webrtc.LibvpxVp9Decoder.nativeIsSupported() (tried Java_org_webrtc_LibvpxVp9Decoder_nativeIsSupported and Java_org_webrtc_LibvpxVp9Decoder_nativeIsSupported__) - is the library loaded, e.g. System.loadLibrary?
    at org.webrtc.LibvpxVp9Decoder.nativeIsSupported(Native Method)
    at org.webrtc.SoftwareVideoDecoderFactory.supportedCodecs(SoftwareVideoDecoderFactory.java:48)
    at org.webrtc.SoftwareVideoDecoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs(SoftwareVideoDecoderFactory.java:41)
    at org.webrtc.DefaultVideoDecoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs(DefaultVideoDecoderFactory.java:60)
    at       io.github.crow_misia.webrtc.RTCComponentFactory.createPeerConnectionFactory(RTCComponentFactory.kt:58)
    at live.videosdk.rtc.android.lib.RoomClient.<init>(RoomClient.java:266)
    at live.videosdk.rtc.android.VideoSDK.initMeeting(VideoSDK.java:156)
    at com.example.videocall.MeetingActivity.onCreate(MeetingActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Comment: Perhaps forget to call System.loadLibrary()?

Comment: Can you share the code from where this error originates from?

Comment: meeting = VideoSDK.initMeeting(
                    MeetingActivity.this, meetingId, participantName,
                    micEnabled, webcamEnabled,null, "UDP_ONLY", "true", true, null);

Comment: @zomega
which library to load ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems you didn't call VideoSDK.initialize(). Please read https://docs.videosdk.live/android/guide/video-and-audio-calling-api-sdk/quick-start

Comment: my code is same [link](https://github.com/videosdk-live/quickstart/tree/main/android-rtc/Videosdk_android_java_quickstart)   and i did call   VideoSDK.initialize()   @zomega

Comment: What is your device?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `VideoSDK.initialize(getApplicationContext());`